# relative import cannot resolve to an ambient module

Tags: typescript

According to typescript documentation (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html):

> A relative import is resolved relative to the importing file and
>   *cannot* resolve to an ambient module declaration.

but also:

> For example, an import statement like import { b } from "./moduleB" in
>   /root/src/moduleA.ts would result in attempting the following
>   locations for locating "./moduleB":

```
/root/src/moduleB.ts
/root/src/moduleB.tsx
/root/src/moduleB.d.ts
/root/src/moduleB/package.json (if it specifies a "typings" property)
/root/src/moduleB/index.ts
/root/src/moduleB/index.tsx
/root/src/moduleB/index.d.ts"
```

The line */root/src/moduleB.d.ts* seems to me as an ambient module declaration used to resolve the relative import "./moduleB" -> exactly what the documentation denies it does.

Am I missing something here or the documentation is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short Answer

> The line /root/src/moduleB.d.ts seems to me as an ambient module declaration... Am I missing something here or the documentation is wrong?

You are missing something here. `moduleB.d.ts` is not an ambient module declaration. Here is an example of a file that contains an ambient module declaration of `moduleB`.

```
// someFile.d.ts 

declare module "moduleB" {
    export class b { }
}
```

The `declare` keyword specifies an ambient declaration.

#### Some Details

About the word ambient, [the documentation says](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html):

> We call declarations that don’t define an implementation “ambient”. Typically, these are defined in .d.ts files.

Ambient declarations include but are not limited to ambient module declarations. A .d.ts file that contains ambient declarations is not an ambient module declaration and does not necessarily contain an ambient module declaration.

For instance, the following greeter.d.ts file contains an ambient class declaration, but it is not an ambient module declaration.

```
// greeter.d.ts

declare class Greeter {
    constructor(greeting: string);
    greeting: string;
}
```

The following `foobar.d.ts` file contains two ambient module declarations of "foo" and "bar", but the file itself is not an ambient module declaration.

```
// foobar.d.ts

declare module "foo" {       
    export function doFoo(foo: string): string;
}

declare module "bar" {
    export function doBar(bar: string): string;
}
```

The documentation that you originally cited states that a relative import of `"./foo"` could not resolve to the above ambient declaration of that module.

#### Further Details

See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

See also: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/issues/180

See also: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html

Comment: hi, thank you but I'm still very confused.

foobar.d.ts file contains two ambient module declarations and is very similar to *node.d.ts* given as an example by https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html in *Ambient Modules* section. Also is almost identical to someFile.d.ts which you said is an ambient module.

Why foobar.d.ts itself is not an ambient module declaration?

Comment: @adrhc `foobar.d.ts` contains two ambient module declarations, but `foobar.d.ts` is not an ambient module declaration. That is because an ambient declaration is not a file. An ambient declaration is a statement that uses the `declare` keyword. Similarly, `someFile.d.ts` contains an ambient module declaration, but the file is not an ambient module declaration, because it is a file. Further, the `node.d.ts` file is not an ambient module declaration; rather, it contains two ambient module declarations of `"url"` and `"path"`.

Comment: ok, then what most probable is/contains /root/src/moduleB.d.ts from my question?
Consider also when thinking at "most probable" to this excerpt from documentation: "We call declarations that don’t define an implementation “ambient”. Typically, these are defined in .d.ts files."

Comment: `moduleB.d.ts` is a declaration file. It probably contains type declarations.

Comment: Thank you  Shaun, it's clearer now. 
So, basically if I put the content of someFile.d.ts into /root/src/moduleB.d.ts it's worthless because while the ts compiler will include /root/src/moduleB.d.ts it won't search for moduleB into it when using `import * as moduleB from "./moduleB"`. Also when using `import * as moduleB from "moduleB"` this won't resolve to /root/src/moduleB.d.ts because it's a non-relative import so moduleB again won't be found into /root/src/moduleB.d.ts. Right?

Comment: @adrhc If we put the content of `someFile.d.ts` into `moduleB.d.ts`, and we `import * as moduleB from "./moduleB"`, the compiler will try to locate `moduleB` at `moduleB.d.ts`, but it won't find a module there, because there is no top level export/import in the file, and because it will ignore ambient module declarations.

Comment: @adrhc Also, when using `import * as moduleB from "moduleB"`, this won't resolve to `moduleB.d.ts`, because it's a non-relative import (which you correctly stated). To import the ambient module with a non-relative import, we could first do a `/// <reference path="moduleB.d.ts"/>`, in which case we could then use the non-relative import.

Comment: man, your comment related to `/// <reference ... />` makes a lot of sense. But the ts "module-resolution" chapter creates the illusion that only ts/tsx/d.ts files referenced in the resolution algorithm shall be used. Additional ts/tsx/d.ts indirectly included through package.json with "typings" property or through tsconfig.json are clearly emphasized; this is not happening for `/// <reference ... />` and I find it misleading. Do you think this point of view legitimate or exaggerated?

Comment: @adrhc You're right in noting that the "How TypeScript resolves modules" section does not list ambient modules. Further up the page in the introduction, though, is this sentence: "If that didn’t work and if the module name is non-relative... then the compiler will attempt to locate an ambient module declaration." Here is the link to that [module resolution chapter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html). My sense is that module resolution is a very complex topic and that, yes, individual docs can give the wrong impression (i.e. they can be misleading).

Comment: related to "If that didn’t work and if the module name is non-relative... then the compiler will attempt to locate an ambient module declaration."
So, an ambient module declaration will always be located by using `/// <reference ... />`?

Comment: The answer is no, because (I quote): "A non-relative import can be resolved relative to baseUrl, or through path mapping, which we’ll cover below. They can also resolve to ambient module declarations" - see [module-resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).